# Fourier transform of a Generalized Gaussian

Tags: fourier-analysis

I've got a family of functions called Generalized Gaussians.

They're given by:

$f(x) = \exp(-ax^{2p})$

Where $p \in \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$

Could anyone tell me how to find their Fourier transforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method: we define $g(t):=\int_{\mathbb R}e^{itx}e^{-x^{2p}}\mathrm dx$. Then, taking the derivative under the integral and integrating by parts, we derive the differential equation
$$g^{(2p-1)}(t)=(-1)^p\frac t{2p}g(t).$$
The solutions of this equation are analytic, hence we can find a recurrence relation between the coefficients.

Comment: I was wondering if you could add a little more details on coefficients to your solution?